# How to get post values from formData in Controller ( Symfony )

Tags: symfony

I created a REST Api. From the front i send post values with axios. (i use ReactJS). In Back with Symfony, in my Controller i want to get post values. How can i do ? I did it:

from the front:

```
const data = new FormData();

       let postData = {
            source: 'lcl',
            userLastname: lastname,
            userFirstname: firstname,
            text: message,
        }

data.append('data', postData);

Axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/send', data)
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error)
        });
```

And from my back in Controller i try this:

```
$data = $request->request->get('data');
```

the value return [object Object]...
How can i get the value (source, userLastname etc.).

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 2):

you should decode your data:

```
$data = $request->request->get('data');

if (!empty($data)) {
    $array = json_decode($data, true); // 2nd param to get ass array
    $userLastname =  $array['userLastname']; // etc...
}
```

Now `$array` will be an array full of your JSON data. Remove the true parameter value in the json_decode() call to get a stdClass object.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I already tried this code, unfortunately it is not work :-(

Comment: Could youprovide the result of `dump($array)` and the `dump($data)`?

Comment: That's not true. Symfony will convert the payload to an array. You don't need to decode. See my answer.

Comment: @msphn could refer me a link in the symfony doc how symony with deserilize the json object automatically

Comment: Sorry, you need https://github.com/symfony-bundles/json-request-bundle. Thought it’s in the default. Guess it even is depending on the skeleton

Answer (score -1):

```
[object Object]
```

That happens if JS converts an object to a string, your payload never reaches your backend. Calling $request->request->get('source') etc. will work.

That happens because you append it to a formdata object which will be implicitly converted to a string, try passing postData just instead of your data. And you will succeed.

Just like

```
Axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/send', postData)
```

Edit:
Sorry, request conversion might be optional. Go for Param listener from fosrestbundle or use https://github.com/symfony-bundles/json-request-bundle

Comment: Actually, i can not do that because i need to send file also. That is why i append with formData.

Comment: Then you need to convert your json before adding it to the form to json and.